# Xcode 10 beta 6 Whole Module setting causes "cannot have input files with file list" error

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile app target using new Xcode 10 (beta 6) using Release configuration. Xcode 10 for Release configuration has `SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE` set to `Whole Module`. Compilation unfortunately finishes with mysterious error:

`<unknown>:0: error: cannot have input files with file list
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code`

Does anyone have idea what can be the source of the problem? It's worth to add that changing `SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE` to `Incremental` causes build to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem. For `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` we were having recursive search path (`"$(PROJECT_DIR)/**"`) that was including many folders in Swift compile part. Specifying concrete framework that we were linking against (`"$(PROJECT_DIR)/<concrete_path_to_framework_folder>"`) solved the problem.